# Azure Active Directory B2C for Xamarin.IOS & Xamarin.Android

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, azure-ad-b2c

I want to implement Azure B2C for Xamarin Native projects. However, I only got solutions for Xamarin.Forms from Microsoft, Xamarin sites and from other blogs. I do not got any example or documentation which explains how to integrate Azure B2C into Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS projects. I would appreciate a help here.

links referred:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Apology that it is against policy. However, it is very new technology and have very less support documents. I have also refer same kind of posts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719583/how-to-sign-into-azure-ad-b2c-using-only-xamarin-ios and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147054/sign-in-with-azure-ad-b2c-to-xamarin-android-app. Also, if you still feel, it is not a valid question, please revert back and I would delete this question.

Comment: Azure Active Directory B2C is used to Xamarin.froms. I think you have to search alternative plugin for authenticating in Xamarin.ios and Xamarin.android.

Comment: @Cola - Let me rephrase what you have commented. Correct me if I am wrong. You said that Azure B2C is only supported/available for Xamarin Forms and not for Xamarin native implementation. Please confirm.